# Reset new coredata managed object to a staged state

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Hi fellow iOS developers, I have seem to run into a roadblock here with coredata and Im fairly certain this is should be a common use case. But I am either not querying google correctly or my design with handling managed objects was bad which led to this problem.

So basically, the problem that I am facing is the following..

1. User creates a new managed object object.
2. User updates said new managed object object (say edit the name
   field)
3. ** The following is the problem ** 
   User wants to edit the same field again, but decides to discard their changes

What is the right thing to do here? Initially I was using .refresh() on the managed object context, but that only works if the object is persisted in the database.

Essentially, I don't want to save the object until the user explicitly opts to "save". Which leaves me in this limbo land. At first one of my thoughts was to created regular objects and convert them into core data objects when "save" is selected. However, that proved to be inefficient especially when handling multiple relationships.

I would think that there is something that is provided that aims to solve this problem, im just not quite querying google correctly.

Comment: Implement `Undo`.

Comment: This [cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org) can be useful for you. [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord)